# I'd like to convert my ed25519 keypair to curve25519 in java (similar as ed2curve in js)

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, ed25519, curve-25519

I'd like to ask if there is any API that supports **converting ed25519 keypairs to curve25519** ones.

Using `ed2curve` for node.js now, and if you have any better recommendation, I'd appreciate your suggestions.

also looking for an API that supports `curve25519` encryption/decryption....
(I tried tweetnacl's nacl.box and had no idea what nonce was)

#### So here's what I need

- converting `ed25519 to curve25519` (to encrypt/decrypt aes256key)  - JAVA api
- `curve25519` encryption/decryption (does bouncy castle do that?)  - JAVA, Javascript

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks, have a great day!

Comment: _Libsodium_ supports the transformation of _Ed25519_ into _X25519_ keys. In Java, _Libsodium_ can be used via various wrapper libraries, e.g. [_Lazysodium_](https://docs.lazycode.co/lazysodium/). The conversion is possible with [`convertKeyPairEd25519ToCurve25519`](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/LazySodium.java). Java itself ([JEP324](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/324)) and _BouncyCastle_ ([Release 2.7.3](https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html)) support _X25519_, but afaik not the conversion.

Comment: @Topaco It's just what i was looking for! Thank you so much! hope you have a wonderful week!